# Fullscreen videos & some apps are viewed in a new workspace

Tags: workspace

I have noticed a weird behavior on Loki. Some apps like Document Viewer or videos in Firefox are switching to a new workspace when chosen to be viewed on fullscreen option and returning to the old workspace when fullscreen is turned off. I don't remember Freya did this. Is this caused by Loki or is it just my system doing this? If not is there any way to keep the apps work fullscreen on the same workspace?

Comment: I have realized that this only happens only when there is another window is open in the same workspace.

Comment: Same thing happens for me, it's really annoying when screen goes back and forth while switching full screen mode.

Comment: Yeah it is really annoying

Comment: Thanks. I feel like this caused by base elementary. I haven't face this issue on Ubuntu 16.04